# how to change position to sorter.phtml block?

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend, xml

i'm trying to move this UI element
`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml` from its original position to the right side of the screen inside another container.

The problem is that i couldn't for the life of me find its name to select it so instead i tried selecting the entire toolbar.phtml block and move it like this:

```
<move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="sidebar.additional" />
```

but nothing changes on the front end.

i found the name **product_list_toolbar** in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml` specifically here:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
     <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</block>
```

Can anyone help?

The ideal would be to move only the sorter element that is found inside toolbar but even if you can help me select the entire toolbar it would be of huge help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello dear I will find your solution so please follow the below steps. I will explain step by step.

Step 1: go to your theme directory and add the below file.

/var/www/html/project/app/design/frontend/Magento/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
 <body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
         <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="custom.toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml" after="-" />
    </referenceContainer> 
</body>
```

Step 2 : /var/www/html/project/app/design/frontend/Magento/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar.phtml

```
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()) :?>
<?php $widget = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonDecode($block->getWidgetOptionsJson());
    $widgetOptions = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($widget['productListToolbarForm']);
?>
<div class="toolbar toolbar-products" data-mage-init='{"productListToolbarForm":<?= /* @noEscape */ $widgetOptions ?>}'>
    <?php if ($block->getIsBottom()): ?>
        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
        <?= $block->fetchView($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml')) ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if ($block->isExpanded()): ?>
            <?= $block->fetchView($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/viewmode.phtml')) ?>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?= $block->fetchView($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar/amount.phtml')) ?>
       
    <?php endif ?>
</div>
```

The above file just removed for **sorter.phtml**

Step 3:

/var/www/html/project/app/design/frontend/Magento/customtheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml

```
<?php $widget = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonDecode($block->getWidgetOptionsJson());
    $widgetOptions = $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data::class)->jsonEncode($widget['productListToolbarForm']);
?>
 <div data-mage-init='{"productListToolbarForm":<?= /* @noEscape */ $widgetOptions ?>}'>
<div class="toolbar-sorter sorter">
<label class="sorter-label" for="sorter"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Sort By')) ?></label>
<select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">
    <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order) :?>
        <option value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_key) ?>"
            <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)) :?>
                selected="selected"
            <?php endif; ?>
            >
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<?php if ($block->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc') :?>
    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Set Ascending Direction')) ?>"
       href="#"
       class="action sorter-action sort-desc"
       data-role="direction-switcher"
       data-value="asc">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Set Ascending Direction')) ?></span>
    </a>
<?php else :?>
    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Set Descending Direction')) ?>"
       href="#"
       class="action sorter-action sort-asc"
       data-role="direction-switcher"
       data-value="desc">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Set Descending Direction')) ?></span>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

i hope that works. so please accept my answer and upvote me.

I will also share my screenshot. for the sorter move in the sidebar additional.

[image]
[image]
[image]

if you any issue so please tell me i will try to help.

Comment: hi, thanks this worked! i have a question though, can you tell me where did you get **custom.toolbar** ? and why did you remove the sorter.phtml element from toolbar.phtml? i thought it was the opposite, it thought sorter.phtml needed to be there or it wouldn't work.

Comment: yes,custom.toolbar was created only. your code moves the element to you are already said sorter toolbar move in the sidebar container. so I will move the sorter toolbar and that is also working in the sidebar additional.

Comment: hello, any issue with this then tell me.